# CUFFT: How to calculate fft of pitched pointer?

Tags: cuda, fft, cufft

I'm trying to calculate the fft of an image using CUFFT. It seems like CUFFT only offers fft of plain device pointers allocated with `cudaMalloc`.

My input images are allocated using `cudaMallocPitch` but there is no option for handling pitch of the image pointer.

Currently, I have to remove the alignment of rows, then execute the fft, and copy back the results to the pitched pointer. My current code is as follows:

```
void fft_device(float* src, cufftComplex* dst, int width, int height, int srcPitch, int dstPitch)
{
    //src and dst are device pointers allocated with cudaMallocPitch

    //Convert them to plain pointers. No padding of rows.
    float *plainSrc;
    cufftComplex *plainDst;

    cudaMalloc<float>(&plainSrc,width * height * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc<cufftComplex>(&plainDst,width * height * sizeof(cufftComplex));

    cudaMemcpy2D(plainSrc,width * sizeof(float),src,srcPitch,width * sizeof(float),height,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

    cufftHandle handle;
    cufftPlan2d(&handle,width,height,CUFFT_R2C);

    cufftSetCompatibilityMode(handle,CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);

    cufftExecR2C(handle,plainSrc,plainDst);

    cufftDestroy(handle);

    cudaMemcpy2D(dst,dstPitch,plainDst,width * sizeof(cufftComplex),width * sizeof(cufftComplex),height,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

    cudaFree(plainSrc);
    cudaFree(plainDst);
}
```

It gives correct result, but I don't want to do 2 extra memory allocations and copies inside the function. I want to do something like this:

```
void fft_device(float* src, cufftComplex* dst, int width, int height, int srcPitch, int dstPitch)
{
    //src and dst are device pointers allocated with cudaMallocPitch
    //Don't know how to handle pitch here???
    cufftHandle handle;
    cufftPlan2d(&handle,width,height,CUFFT_R2C);

    cufftSetCompatibilityMode(handle,CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);

    cufftExecR2C(handle,src,dst);

    cufftDestroy(handle);
}
```

## Question:

How to calculate the fft of pitched pointer directly using CUFFT?

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment, apparently inembed and onembed are the key when using cufftPlanMany.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20853235/1939814, which does yield correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be interested in `cufftPlanMany` which would let you do 1D, 2D, and 3D ffts with pitches. The key here is inembed and onembed parameters.

You can look up CUDA_CUFFT_Users_Guide.pdf (Pages 23-24) for more information. But for your example, you'd be doing something like the follows.

```
void fft_device(float* src, cufftComplex* dst,
                int width, int height,
                int srcPitch, int dstPitch)
{
    cufftHandle handle;
    int rank = 2; // 2D fft
    int n[] = {width, height};    // Size of the Fourier transform
    int istride = 1, ostride = 1; // Stride lengths
    int idist = 1, odist = 1;     // Distance between batches
    int inembed[] = {srcPitch, height}; // Input size with pitch
    int onembed[] = {dstPitch, height}; // Output size with pitch
    int batch = 1;
    cufftPlanMany(&handle, rank, n, 
                  inembed, istride, idist,
                  onembed, ostride, odist, CUFFT_R2C, batch);

    cufftSetCompatibilityMode(handle,CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);
    cufftExecR2C(handle,src,dst);
    cufftDestroy(handle);
}
```

P.S. I did not add return checks for the sake of example here. Always check for return values in your code.

Comment: I tried the above code, but it is still not working. The output contains garbage values.

Comment: @sgar91 srcPitch and dstPitch should be in number of elements, not in bytes (as for cudamemcpy2d)

Comment: Yes, I specified pitch as number of elements by doing `srcPitch/sizeof(float)` and `dstPitch/sizeof(cufftComplex)`. Still getting incorrect output.