# CUFFT : How to calculate the fft when the input is a pitched array

Tags: c++, cuda, fft, dynamic-arrays, cufft

I'm trying to find the fft of a dynamically allocated array. The input array is copied from host to device using `cudaMemcpy2D`. Then the fft is taken (cufftExecR2C) and the results are copied back from device to host.

So my initial problem was how to use the pitch information in the fft. Then I found an answer here - [CUFFT: How to calculate fft of pitched pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026900/cufft-how-to-calculate-fft-of-pitched-pointer)

But unfortunately it doesn't work. The results I get are garbage values. Given below is my code.

```
#define NRANK 2
#define BATCH 10

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const size_t NX = 4;
const size_t NY = 6;

int main()
    { 
    // Input array (static) - host side 
    float h_in_data_static[NX][NY] ={ 
        {0.7943 ,   0.6020 ,   0.7482  ,  0.9133  ,  0.9961 , 0.9261},
        {0.3112 ,   0.2630 ,   0.4505  ,  0.1524  ,  0.0782 ,  0.1782},
        {0.5285 ,   0.6541 ,   0.0838  ,  0.8258  ,  0.4427,  0.3842},
        {0.1656 ,   0.6892 ,   0.2290  ,  0.5383  ,  0.1067,  0.1712}
        };

    // --------------------------------
    // Input array (dynamic) - host side 
    float *h_in_data_dynamic = new float[NX*NY];  

    // Set the values
    size_t h_ipitch;
    for (int r = 0; r < NX; ++r)  // this can be also done on GPU
        {    
        for (int c = 0; c < NY; ++c)
            {   h_in_data_dynamic[NY*r + c] = h_in_data_static[r][c];   }
        }
    // --------------------------------

    // Output array - host side
    float2 *h_out_data_temp = new float2[NX*(NY/2+1)] ; 


    // Input and Output array - device side 
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftReal *d_in_data;      
    cufftComplex * d_out_data;
    int n[NRANK] = {NX, NY};

    //  Copy input array from Host to Device
    size_t ipitch;
    cudaError  cudaStat1 =  cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_in_data,&ipitch,NY*sizeof(cufftReal),NX);    
    cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat1) << endl;
    cudaError  cudaStat2 =  cudaMemcpy2D(d_in_data,ipitch,h_in_data_dynamic,NY*sizeof(float),NY*sizeof(float),NX,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   
    cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat2) << endl;

    //  Allocate memory for output array - device side
    size_t opitch;
    cudaError  cudaStat3 =  cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_out_data,&opitch,(NY/2+1)*sizeof(cufftComplex),NX);  
    cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat3) << endl;

    //  Performe the fft
    int rank = 2; // 2D fft     
    int istride = 1, ostride = 1; // Stride lengths
    int idist = 1, odist = 1;     // Distance between batches
    int inembed[] = {ipitch, NX}; // Input size with pitch
    int onembed[] = {opitch, NX}; // Output size with pitch
    int batch = 1;
    cufftPlanMany(&plan, rank, n, inembed, istride, idist, onembed, ostride, odist, CUFFT_R2C, batch);
    //cufftPlan2d(&plan, NX, NY , CUFFT_R2C);
    cufftSetCompatibilityMode(plan, CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);
    cufftExecR2C(plan, d_in_data, d_out_data);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    // Copy d_in_data back from device to host
    cudaError  cudaStat4 = cudaMemcpy2D(h_out_data_temp,(NY/2+1)*sizeof(float2), d_out_data, opitch, (NY/2+1)*sizeof(cufftComplex), NX, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
    cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat4) << endl;

    // Print the results
    for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)    
        {
        for (int j =0 ; j< NY/2 + 1; j++)       
            printf(" %f + %fi",h_out_data_temp[i*(NY/2+1) + j].x ,h_out_data_temp[i*(NY/2+1) + j].y);
        printf("\n");    
        }
    cudaFree(d_in_data);

    return 0;
    }
```

I think the problem is in `cufftPlanMany`. How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to study the [advanced data layout section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#advanced-data-layout) of the documentation carefully.

I think the previous question that was linked is somewhat confusing because that question is passing the `width` and `height` parameters in reverse order for what I would expect for a cufft 2D plan.  However the answer then mimics that order so it is at least consistent.

Secondly, you missed in the previous question that the "pitch" parameters that are being passed in `inembed` and `onembed` are *not the same* as the pitch parameters that you would receive from a `cudaMallocPitch` operation.  They have to be scaled by the number of bytes per data element in the input and output data sets.  I'm actually not entirely sure this is the intended use of the `inembed` and `onembed` parameters, but it seems to work.

When I adjust your code to account for the above two changes, I seem to get valid results, at least they appear to be in a reasonable range.  You've posted several questions now about 2D FFTs, where you've said the results are not correct.  I can't do these 2D FFT's in my head, so I suggest in the future you indicate what data you are expecting.

This has the changes I made:

```
#define NRANK 2
#define BATCH 10

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const size_t NX = 4;
const size_t NY = 6;

int main()
    {
    // Input array (static) - host side
    float h_in_data_static[NX][NY] ={
        {0.7943 ,   0.6020 ,   0.7482  ,  0.9133  ,  0.9961 , 0.9261},
        {0.3112 ,   0.2630 ,   0.4505  ,  0.1524  ,  0.0782 ,  0.1782},
        {0.5285 ,   0.6541 ,   0.0838  ,  0.8258  ,  0.4427,  0.3842},
        {0.1656 ,   0.6892 ,   0.2290  ,  0.5383  ,  0.1067,  0.1712}
        };

    // --------------------------------
    // Input array (dynamic) - host side
    float *h_in_data_dynamic = new float[NX*NY];

    // Set the values
    size_t h_ipitch;
    for (int r = 0; r < NX; ++r)  // this can be also done on GPU
        {
        for (int c = 0; c < NY; ++c)
            {   h_in_data_dynamic[NY*r + c] = h_in_data_static[r][c];   }
        }
    // --------------------------------
    int owidth = (NY/2)+1;

    // Output array - host side
    float2 *h_out_data_temp = new float2[NX*owidth] ;


    // Input and Output array - device side
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftReal *d_in_data;
    cufftComplex * d_out_data;
    int n[NRANK] = {NX, NY};

    //  Copy input array from Host to Device
    size_t ipitch;
    cudaError  cudaStat1 =  cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_in_data,&ipitch,NY*sizeof(cufftReal),NX);
    cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat1) << endl;
    cudaError  cudaStat2 =  cudaMemcpy2D(d_in_data,ipitch,h_in_data_dynamic,NY*sizeof(float),NY*sizeof(float),NX,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat2) << endl;

    //  Allocate memory for output array - device side
    size_t opitch;
    cudaError  cudaStat3 =  cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_out_data,&opitch,owidth*sizeof(cufftComplex),NX);
    cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat3) << endl;

    //  Performe the fft
    int rank = 2; // 2D fft
    int istride = 1, ostride = 1; // Stride lengths
    int idist = 1, odist = 1;     // Distance between batches
    int inembed[] = {NX, ipitch/sizeof(cufftReal)}; // Input size with pitch
    int onembed[] = {NX, opitch/sizeof(cufftComplex)}; // Output size with pitch
    int batch = 1;
    if ((cufftPlanMany(&plan, rank, n, inembed, istride, idist, onembed, ostride, odist, CUFFT_R2C, batch)) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) cout<< "cufft error 1" << endl;
    //cufftPlan2d(&plan, NX, NY , CUFFT_R2C);
    if ((cufftSetCompatibilityMode(plan, CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE)) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) cout << "cufft error 2" << endl;
    if ((cufftExecR2C(plan, d_in_data, d_out_data)) != CUFFT_SUCCESS) cout << "cufft error 3" << endl;
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Copy d_in_data back from device to host
    cudaError  cudaStat4 = cudaMemcpy2D(h_out_data_temp,owidth*sizeof(float2), d_out_data, opitch, owidth*sizeof(cufftComplex), NX, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cout << cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat4) << endl;

    // Print the results
    for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
        {
        for (int j =0 ; j< owidth; j++)
            printf(" %f + %fi",h_out_data_temp[i*owidth + j].x ,h_out_data_temp[i*owidth + j].y);
        printf("\n");
        }
    cudaFree(d_in_data);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for your answer. I have counterchecked the output of the above code with Matlab and it seems that the non-redundant parts of the output perfectly match Matlab's `fft2`.

Comment: Thanks, I just finished checking it in Octave.

Comment: Priceless answer. And kudos to those who verified it.